# Caching in .Net Windows application

Tags: c#, .net, caching

I am working in a windows based application which uses master data for every transaction. This master data normally doesn't change but in some cases it can be change. I am fetching this data into cache or `DataSet` once and use it for future transactions, but don't want to use time to extract data from database if data get changed in master table.

I want to create a dependency on a `DataTable` so that if data get changed only at that time it get information from database. As It is a windows based application and I didn't found any support for caching in Windows application, how can I do this either by caching or by `DataSet`?

Comment: Man, screwing around with `DataTable` and `DataSet` is *rarely* needed. Why don't you get yourself a good ol' ORM to do this stuff for you? Most of the common ones support both first and second level caching.

Comment: Are your server really that slow? i.e. so slow that you can't use the database to read and update data? If that's the case, something is seriuosly wrong. In the other case, you are doing premature optimizations or working with too large result sets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> "As It is a windows based application and I didn't found any support for caching in Windows application"

This is False.

You can get caching class in Framework 4.0. It can be either windows based applications or web-based. Here are the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx).

Example:

```
 using System.Runtime.Caching;

 private static MemoryCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you use the [Enterprise Library Caching block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649093.aspx)?

Comment: 2005 called... They wanted their link back :)

Comment: @David - Once they integrated System.Runtime.Caching into .NET 4.0 they deprecated the Enterprise Caching Block. Per MSF "Caching Application Block functionality is built into .NET Framework 4.0; therefore the Enterprise Library Caching Application Block will be deprecated in releases after 5.0. You should consider using the .NET 4.0 System.Runtime.Caching classes instead of the Caching Application Block in future development." see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664753(v=pandp.50).aspx